# How to copy all files except one file and one directory to another directory

Tags: macos, jenkins, terminal

I have the following directory

1. Dir A:

   - .git --> this is a directory
   - .gitignore
   - Dir B
   - Dir C
   - Dir E
   - file f
   - file g
   - Dir H

I want to copy everything except for (.git, .gitignore and Dir B) to Dir B. (Dir B is under Dir A)

I have tried the following

```
cp -r !(Dir B|.git|.gitignore) ~/Dir B
```

This works as expected when run it in terminal, but gives me  an  error when i run it from the Jenkins Shell window.

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Please Advice

Comment: Which shell (bin, bash,...) are you using when you successfully run the command on the terminal? Also, can you paste the output of `ls -l /bin/sh`?

Comment: Do you want to copy any hidden file/directory too into 'Dir B'?

Comment: Although not much related to issue at hand but there's some typo too because your statements are contradictory. You've mentioned that `Dir B is under Dir A` but in your command, you've used `~/Dir B`. I'm sure home dir will not be `/home/Dir A`.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command -

```
rsync -r --exclude='.*' --exclude='DirB' ./ DirB
```

Comment: what does this command do? why use this over another approach? Explain more pls

Answer (score 1):

I am making the assumption that you *do not* want to copy any *hidden* file/directory to your destination folder i.e., `Dir B`. If it is so, just use the following commands and use them in the *same shell* as shown in the snapshot below:

[image]

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -r !(Dir B) 'Dir B'
shopt -u extglob
```

You don't have to explicitly specify the *.git* dir and *.gitignore* file. Also, you can change the destination dir mentioned above (`'Dir B'`) as per your need/configuration.